# Highchart js set marker at starting of graph

Tags: css, highcharts

I have created a line graph using highchart js .I want to set a grey color marker at the starting and a red colored mrker at the end of my graph.Is there a way to do it with highcharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the load event (`chart.events.load`) you can extract first and last point from series. Then call [update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) function to modify `fillColor` parameter.

```
chart:{
        events:{
        load:function() {
            var chart = this,
                series = chart.series[0],
              data = series.data,
              len = data.length;

          //first point
          data[0].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'gray'
            }
          },false);

          //last point
          data[len - 1].update({
            marker:{
                fillColor: 'red'
            }
          });

        }
      }
    },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/s9erv8f0/

Comment: What if the graph is dynamic ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y1Lpg37x/     ,have a look at this..the markers are not coming ,also the tooltip overlaps for the same value of x axis.This should not happen.

Comment: Marker not appears because you set the "enabled" param as false. Fixed demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zfcqy15j/. You can control tooltip position by [tooltip.positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner)